# Proteus PCB board shape

Tags: pcb, proteus

I'm having difficulties editing or cutting a section of a PCB board in Proteus.

I want to remove the section marked with an "X" since it's unused.

[image]

Comment: what is the difficulty that you are having?

Comment: Thanks I succeeded. I used 2D drawing mode.